# Dynamic prop to teleport component is undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm having trouble with passing dynamic props to a component. It keeps passing an undefined value.

main.vue

```
const guessedRank = reactive({
  value: ""
})

watch(guessedRank, (newVal) => {
  if (newVal) {
    toggleModal();
  }
});

const showResults = (subRank) => {
  guessedRank.value = subRank;
};

const toggleModal = () => {
  showModal.value = !showModal.value;
};

<teleport to=".modals">
  <ResultsModal
      :guessed-rank="guessedRank.value"
      :show="showModal"
      @close-modal="toggleModal"
  />
</teleport>

<TransitionGroup name="list" tag="ul" class="subranks__list">
  <li v-for="subRank in getSubRanks" :key="subRank" class="subrank__item">
    <img :src="`/ranks/${subRank}.png`" :alt="subRank" @click="showResults(subRank)">
  </li>
</TransitionGroup>
```

ResultsModal.vue

```
const {show, guessedRank} = defineProps({
  show: Boolean,
  guessedRank: String
})

const { mutateAsync } = useMutation({
  mutationFn: guessClip,
})

const onModalEnter = async () => {
  console.log("Guessed rank: " + guessedRank); //undefined
  await mutateAsync({
    clipId: "a7feae04-b175-4596-8173-862675c29de7",
    subRank: guessedRank
  });
};

<Transition :duration="550" name="modal" @after-enter="onModalEnter">
  <div class="backdrop" v-if="show">
    <--some code -->
  </div>
</Transition>
```

The guessedRank prop in ResultsModal is undefined

I have tried using a watcher to guessedRank so once it changes, the ResultsModal will appear with that value; however, it shows an undefined value

Comment: It may depend on how the prop is defined and used in ResultsModal.  Can you show?

Comment: @yoduh I've already edited the question so you can see how I'm using the prop. When the ResultsModal appears, it makes a call to an endpoint, but I can't do it because of the undefined prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually destructure `defineProps`.  It loses reactivity that way.

```js
const {show, guessedRank} = defineProps({
  show: Boolean,
  guessedRank: String
})
```

There is a mention of this in the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactive-props-destructure)

> Similar to .value, you need to always access props as props.x in order to retain reactivity. This means you cannot destructure defineProps because the resulting destructured variables are not reactive and will not update.

You should define your props like this instead:

```js
const props = defineProps({
  show: Boolean,
  guessedRank: String
})
```

Then, elsewhere in your script code you would reference a prop like so:

```js
console.log("Guessed rank: " + props.guessedRank);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot!